# What is the answer to this jumble?

Tags: word, anagram, humor

[image: Problem]

I figured out that the answers to the minor questions are-

1. > METAL
2. > MOUTH
3. > RABBIT
4. > ISLAND

And therefore that the letters for the main question are

> MELMHAITISD.

What is the final answer?

<sub>Source: [T2 Jumbles](http://www.telegraphindia.com/jumble/).</sub>

Comment: This would have been better if you hadn't worked out the minor questions for us

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I spoilertagged them, so that people can have a go at this without knowing the minor questions' solutions if they want to

Comment: I've rolled this back to eliminate the link to the "other jumbles" which is not necessary for the puzzle and seems like advertising.

Comment: @DanRussell it was requested by someone

Comment: @DanRussell A link is required to avoid this puzzle getting deleted for plagiarism. I just edited it back in but made it sound less like advertising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> MISLAID THEM

These two words form an anagram of "MELMHAITISD", and they also complete the joke in the cartoon in a meaningful and humorous way.

Comment: Ahh too quick +1

Comment: Damn that was fast!